# estimate clustering of directed graphs

Tags: r, igraph

In order to estimate clustering in [our network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMtDn.jpg), we use the clustering coefficient and the calculation function proposed in [(Kolaczyk, Csardi, 2014, p. 82)](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781493909827). This coefficient is defined as the average, over all vertices v, of the vertex-specific clustering coefficients where A is the adjacency matrix and d^{tot}_v is the total degree (i.e., in-degree plus out-degree) of vertex v.

But applying above eq. (5.4) to our network gave wrong result (NaN). The calculation of the clustering coefficient was done with the following function

```
clust.coef.dir <- function(graph) {
A <- as.matrix(get.adjacency(graph))
S <- A + t(A)
deg <- degree(graph, mode=c("total"))
num <- diag(S %*% S %*% S)
denom <- diag(A %*% A)
denom <- 2 * (deg * (deg - 1) - 2 * denom)
# denominator equals 0 for vertex A10
cl <- mean(num / denom)
return(cl)
}
```

The reason of this wrong result is the vertex A10. 
The total degree d^{tot}_{A10}=2 therefore 
deg * (deg - 1) = 2 * denom then denom = 0 for vertex A10.

How to improve this situation to such case? 
Many thanks.

Comment: Leave out that vertex? E.g. `mean(num / denom, na.rm = TRUE)`. Btw. igraph has functions for the clustering coefficient, too.

Comment: @Gabor, thanks you for reply. Did you mean [transitivity()](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/transitivity) or not? Our graph is directed. I tried transitivity() and transitivity(as.undirected(g, mode = "collapse")). Results are equal.